# C++ Creating an instance of a class outside of the main() function

Tags: c++, class

I have a class where in the constructor, I simply do: printf("Hello");
If I make an instance of that class outside of the main() function, "Hello" does not pop up in my debug menu. However if I make an instance of the class inside of the main() function, "Hello" does indeed pop up.

Why does it have to be created inside of the main() function? Is there a way I can make it work when I put it outside of the main() function?

```
SomeClass instance;

int main(){

}
```

Compared to:

```
int main(){
    SomeClass instance;
}
```

Comment: Try to make some use of the global object in your `main` function -- perhaps the compiler optimized the global away because it wasn't being used. Or make the global a `static const`. What optimization options are you using?

Answer (score 3):

For the static instance of the class I imagine the constructor runs before the debug console is ready to receive output from `printf`.  This sort of code is probably very implementation specific.

Comment: It's probably the sending side rather than the receiving side.  `stdout` might not be initialized yet.

Comment: I think the file descriptors are initialized by the parent process before the child process is started, so why wouldn't stdout not be "initialized?"